# Python3 pyinstaller --onefile запуск файла в фоновом (скрытом/daemon) режиме

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, windows-10, pyinstaller, daemon

Цель: Сделать так чтоб при запуске откомпилированного в .exe файла он автоматически запускался в фоновом (daemon) режиме, чтоб это выглядело так же как и если запустить просто .pyw файл
Либо скажите то как можно добавить программу в автозапуск через cmd таким способом чтоб она запускалась в daemon режиме 
Буду очень благодарен за ответ !

Comment: Я конечно знаю что есть способ  такого запуска с помощью vba скрипта, но он работает не всегда корректно + всё таки хочется чтоб файл был один и только один

Comment: не знаю что такое демон в контексте Винды (системный сервис?), но если вы хотите pyw эффект получить, то собирайте как GUI приложение (--noconsole? или просто pyw файл на вход попробуйте)

Comment: @jfs Спасибо! --noconsole подошел и работает так как мне нужно. Но если .pyw на выход попробовать то всё равно консоль выскакивает при запуске .exe шника :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole